# Error when trying to mup deploy

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm getting a few deploy errors when trying to deploying an app to AWS.

I had a cordova issue which i think i've fixed but am currently getting this error:

```
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/peggy/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
gyp info ok 
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
    App did not pick up! Please check app logs.
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    js

```
`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
ansi-regex@0.2.1 node_modules/ansi-regex

ansi-styles@1.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

escape-string-regexp@1.0.3 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline

type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of

amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine

asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap

underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

meteor-promise@0.5.0 node_modules/meteor-promise

promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise

source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
connected
peggy stop/waiting
peggy start/running, process 5739
Waiting for 10 seconds while app is booting up
Checking is app booted or not?
-------------------------------
```

Any ideas. I've searched a lot of other threads but am at a loss.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it's as simple as increasing the `deployCheckWaitTime` from default 15 to 60 or even 120.